# ubuntu 13.10 installation on sony vaio

Tags: 13.04, graphics, vaio, sony

i want to install ubuntu 13.10 on my sony vaio-sve15125 along side windows 8,so can you guys please tell me if AMD Radeon™ HD 7650M is supported with this version of Ubuntu? As i have faced issues regarding installation with the previous version of ubuntu 13.04 resulting to a purple splash screen on bootup and the installation never went further.
So please help me out with this.

thanks and regards 
Riz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the AMD Catalyst 12+ driver.

From here:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst1211betadriver.aspx

This is the latest one:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86

Comment: hey witch craft,
Thanks for your prompt input, but at present am running windows 8 so i guess these drivers wont be compatible with windows,is there any work around for the above? coz am unable to install Ubuntu on my machine and to install these drivers i got to be logged in to Ubuntu right?